# Xcode Change Container Alignment on Device Rotation

Tags: ios, xcode, view, uiimage

First time poster, so it won't let me add images.

I've started building my first app ever (outside of "Hello, Word" and "Game of War)

I can't figure out a good strategy to changing container alignments when rotating iOS device.

I would like to make my game playable on iPhone and iPad.

Each 'View' container has a UIImage in it (so I can keep the image at the proper orientation).

In 'Portrait' mode, my containers are lined up like this:

|   x   |
|   y   |
|   z   |

In 'Landscape' mode, I would like my containers to not be aligned horizontally, so I don't have to make my images super small. I really wish I could post an image to show you.

Imagine "x,y,z" above, except 'x' is to the right of 'y', and 'z' to the left of y.  The bottom of 'x' is lined up about the center of 'y', and the top of 'z' is lined up about the center of y.

Sorry, I tried making this as clear as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own using the following article.

http://corsarus.com/2015/adaptive-layout-part-2-working-with-interface-builder/

I hope this helps someone else.